# Images not appearing on page or in channel when edited

Tags: image-galleries

I am  having a bit of an issue with images not displaying (I'm on EE 2.9), even though it looks as if everything is alright in the source code. The page in question is www.westeros.org/ASoWS/Gallery/

The issue also persists internally -- if I go to this channel and look at the entries, the image thumbnails do not show up in the designated field.

I just can't figure out what would be stopping them from appearing -- if I paste in any of the image urls in the source of the page, they're clearly there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protocol of the images is wrong. It should be `http://`, but you're using `http:/`.

Take a look at the [File Upload Preferences](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/files/file_upload_preferences.html#create-edit-upload-destination) of the images in question. Probably the [URL of Upload Directory](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/files/file_upload_preferences.html#url-of-upload-directory) is set wrong.

Comment: Doh! Thanks, I was staring at it and I guess my mind filled in that second slash.